# Getting a list of public Google+ URLs from Google API call?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm a pretty rudimentary programmer - I've got a project from work that basically needs me to assemble a spreadsheet of around 8000 public Google+ URLs. I'm having some issues understanding the Developers Console, as a beginner.

I'm looking to return a list of URLs and Google+ Display names of all profiles that have a specific word in the display name (these are all corporate accounts).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [people.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) API method. This will return a list of people and pages that match the `query`. The results are not limited to searching `displayName` so you will have to do further filtering server side.